# I am getting `Class "Mpdf\Mpdf" not found` in laravel php 8

Tags: laravel, mpdf, php-8

I am getting error as
Error

```
  Class "Mpdf\Mpdf" not found

 
     85▕     public function generatePdf()
     86▕     {
     87▕     include_once base_path('config/mpdf.php');
     88▕     require_once base_path('vendor/autoload.php');
  ➜  89▕     $mpdf = new Mpdf();
     90▕     $mpdf->AddPageByArray([
     91▕         'margin-left' => 0,
     92▕         'margin-right' => 0,
     93▕         'margin-top' => 0,
```

I tried reinstalling the mpdf `composer require mpdf/mpdf`
Also tried using `composer dump-autoload` , updated composer as well
This is my composer.json [image]

Also there is a mpdf folder present in vendor - checked .
Can anyone please help me with this issue....

Comment: `Mpdf\Mpdf` is not the proper namespace for v6, this was first introduced in v7. Keep in mind that v6 is pretty outdated

Comment: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/tree/6.1/examples has v6 examples that might help

Comment: mPDF 6.x is also definitely not compatible with PHP 8. Check readme for compatibility table and preferrably use the last version.

Comment: bit it was worrking fine a month ago - @Finwe

Comment: mPDF 6.x on PHP 8 couldn't have, something must have changed - either you downgraded mPDF or you upgraded PHP. @vaishnavi

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to check the documentation for mpdf on how to propperly initiate the mpdf library.

There is an example on the Github Repo:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf#usage

With more context, i could understand, why you are using v6 - maybe because of PHP 5? Just gessing.

If you want to use MPDF6, you have to initiate it like this:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/mpdf/mpdf.php';

//Create v6 compatible instance.
$mpdf = new mPDF();

// Generate the PDF from you html
$html = '<h1>Hallo Welt</h1>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The code you've shared is not working on mPDF v6

Comment: Thanks for the downvote @NicoHaase - i think the author would really appreciate a propper way to instanciate mpdf instead of downvoting posts and answers :) - i have added a v6 compatible answer.

Comment: `require_once __DIR__ . '/mpdf/mpdf.php';`   - do i need to download mpdf externally ? as my root location is not having mpdf dir , i am justing having mpdf in my vendors folder .. i  update the line as `require_once base_path('vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php');` 
 but still getting error as 'PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported ' @Lukas

Comment: i am using php 8 - i think mpdf v 6 is not supporting , may be i need to update the mpdf version

Comment: @vaishnavi please don't ask new questions in the comment section. Add all details to your initial request instead